# Windows store apps, Encryption,The supplied user buffer is not valid for the requested operation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, encryption, windows-8

I am trying to implement a simple Encryption of a string.

I am getting "The supplied user buffer is not valid for the requested operation" error.
I dont know what is the problem in the implementation.

Below is the code snippet.

```
var keyHash = GetMD5Hash(key);

var toDecryptBuffer = CryptographicBuffer.ConvertStringToBinary(toEncrypt, BinaryStringEncoding.Utf8);

var aes = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.AesEcb);

var symetricKey = aes.CreateSymmetricKey(keyHash);

var buffEncrypted = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(symetricKey, toDecryptBuffer, null);
```

`

Comment: On which line does the exception occur?

Comment: The error occurs in var buffEncrypted = CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(symetricKey, toDecryptBuffer, null);

Answer (score 6):

The length of the data in `toEncrypt` must be a multiple of the block length of the algorithm unless you are using PKCS7 padding, which you currently aren't. You need to manually pad the data or use PKCS7 padding.

```
var aes = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(SymmetricAlgorithmNames.aesEcbPkcs7);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Sani Huttunen. What is the difference If i use AesEcbPkcs7 instead of AesEcb. Will there be any implementation change?

Comment: The difference is only how the data is packaged. The data is padded to a multiple of the algorithms block size. There shouldn't be any other implementation changes, other than to use AesEcbPkcs7 in decrypt aswell.

Comment: ECB mode is insecure.  Use CBC or CTR instead.  If you also need authentication then try GCM.  ECB is only for toy or training systems.

Comment: Hmm that didn't do it for me.. my buffer is smaller than the block size perhaps that is excluded from padding?